# Sending mail via oracle forms6i

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, while-loop, oracleforms

I have the following code

```
Declare
  Outlook_Object OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
  Mail_Object OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;

  Item1 OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
  Item2 OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;

  OLEPARAM ole2.list_type;

  var_Send OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
    var_exit OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;

  var_Attach1 OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
  var_Attach2 OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;

BEGIN

SET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY(CURSOR_STYLE,'BUSY');

  Outlook_Object := OLE2.CREATE_OBJ('Outlook.Application'); 

  OLEPARAM := OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(OLEPARAM,'MAPI');
  Mail_Object := OLE2.INVOKE_OBJ(Outlook_Object,'GetNameSpace',OLEPARAM);
  OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST( OLEPARAM );

--newMail
  OLEPARAM := OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(OLEPARAM,0);
  Item1 := OLE2.INVOKE_OBJ(Outlook_Object,'CreateItem',OLEPARAM);
  OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST( OLEPARAM );

-- If you want to display outlook new message screen
-- Item2 := OLE2.INVOKE_OBJ(Item1,'Display');

  ole2.set_property(Item1,'To',:To);

  ole2.set_property(Item1,'Subject',:Subject);
  ole2.set_property(Item1,'Body',:Body);
 -- ole2.set_property(Item1,'Date',:F_DT);
  --ole2.set_property(Item1,'Date',:F_DT1);
   while :F_DT1 = sysdate 
   loop
    OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ( Item1);
    OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ( Mail_Object );
    OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ( Outlook_Object );
        var_Send := OLE2.INVOKE_OBJ(Item1,'Send');

        SET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY(CURSOR_STYLE,'DEFAULT');
        Message('Mail sent seccessfully.........');
        Message('Mail sent seccessfully.........');

        if :F_DT1 > :F_DT then
        exit_form;
        end if;
                F_DT1 := F_DT+1;
            end loop;
      end;
   I
```

Here F_DT1 = The date from which mail should be sent.
     F_DT = The date till which mail should be sent.
For example I have event on 8th dec 2017 and i need its reminder mail to be received from 4th dec 2017 then I shall put F_DT1 = 4th dec 2017 and F_DT = 8th dec 2017.

Iam not facing any error but Iam not receiving any mail either. Is my logic correct?
[image: This is my oracle form]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer sending mails from the database, using UTL_MAIL (or UTL_SMTP) package. Why? Because I *know* how to do that, as opposed to code you use :)

Obviously, I can't assist with the original question, but I can offer a workaround.

I know that this is a month-old question so you might have already solved the problem. If not, and if you need assistance with UTL_MAIL, say so.